# batch extraction of features - csv files not stored

Tags: audio, pyaudioanalysis

I want to extract audio features from a large set of files using pyaudioanalysis, using the following command line (as suggested on the github project's page):

`python3 audioAnalysis.py featureExtractionDir -i data/ -mw 1.0 -ms 1.0 -sw 0.050 -ss 0.050`

This seems to indeed run the feature extraction - it takes time and return to prompt without error - but does not write any csv files.

Any hint about why this does not work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

the files to be analyzed were actually ADPCM-compressed files, which apparently does not work. Therefore, this led to the following error (in the background, it was NOT returned, and only discovered while trying to run the command in a system call in R):

ValueError: Unknown wave file format: DVI_ADPCM. Supported formats: PCM, IEEE_FLOAT

Once files were uncompressed, the pyAudioAnalysis call worked as expected.